# CSS styling issue - scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a menu (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machismo/vhFX3/)). I have text box which will be hidden in some cases, shown in some cases, so divs below that should adjust the position when `textbox` is hidden. The `listitems` div contains lot of list items. The bottom div should be at the bottom of the screen. `maindiv`'s position should be fixed. Menu area div at the end cannot be removed. Something with the style definition is messed up, I cannot scroll down to the last item. Is there a way to do it without assigning specific height for listitems div?

I'm trying to get something like this. http://tinypic.com/r/1t0sat/6

Any hints or pointers will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. Any diagram/paint sketch greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pinouchon, here is a link to a diagram http://tinypic.com/r/1t0sat/6

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to update your css according to your requierment. Check it. I hope you find your solution.

```
 #mainDiv {
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;   
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    z-index: 30;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    background-color: rgb(0, 87, 71);
}
#mainDiv .MainContentArea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
     height:auto !important;
    min-width: 240px;
     min-height:100%;
}
#mainDiv .HeadingArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    background-color: rgb(96, 76, 91);
}
#mainDiv .InputArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
#mainDiv .SubTitleArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
#mainDivSearch input[type='text'] {
    width: 220px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
#mainDiv input[type='checkbox'] {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#mainDiv .ContentArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;

}
#mainDiv .MenuArea {
   width:100%;
    height: 28px;
    text-align: center;

    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(216, 176, 131);

}
#ContentListArea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#ContentListArea .Options2Area {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom-color: #afafaf;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;

}
#ContentListArea .ListItemsArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 32px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 18px;

}
.ItemList li {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.ItemList li .ItemArea {

    height: 15px;
}
.ItemList li .ItemDetail {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.ItemList li .ItemLabel {
    padding-top: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
textarea, select, input[type=text] {
    width: 99%;
    overflow: auto;

}

body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `<div id="mainDiv" style="left: 198px; top: 101px; display: block;">` with `<div id="mainDiv" style="left: 198px; display: block;">` and remove `<div class="MenuArea"></div>`

Comment: I need that MenuArea to appear there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set **height** for `#ContentListArea .ListItemsArea` in the style as below

```
#ContentListArea .ListItemsArea {
left: 0px;
top: 32px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
overflow: auto;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
padding-left: 18px;
position: absolute;
height: 193px;/*change this according to your  need*/
```

}

fiddle demo  http://jsfiddle.net/krish/vhFX3/1/

Comment: I want the menu to start from the given offset and go till the end of the screen. The list item area should fill the space.

Answer (score 0):

replace your own code fragment with mine in CSS

```
#ContentListArea .ListItemsArea {
    left: 0px;
    top: 32px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    //position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
}
```

give it an appropriate height so that it can scroll within that height.

Comment: I want that div to go till the bottom div. Check out the question for the diagram.

Comment: You want green background div till the end of the page...??? and what about light brown div at the bottom...?? Please clearify it